# CMake fails identifying C++ compiler version in new builds

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, cmake, c++14

Something quite weird is happening to me: CMake fails to choose the correct version of g++ **only** if I compile a project for the first time (or I delete 'build' folder).

So a 'fresh' compilation brings error when using `auto` but if I compile it again, everything goes smoothly (until I delete 'build' folder).

Here you are my files:

CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
    include/*.h
    src/*.cpp
)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14")

set(filename $ENV{env_filename})

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( filename )
add_executable( ${filename} ${filename}.cpp ${SOURCES})
```

compile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
set -e
source filedata.txt
export env_filename=$filename
mkdir -p build && cd build
cmake ..  &> /dev/null
make -B
./$filename
```

filedata.txt

```
filename="1_Example"
```

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

Comment: I don't really see why you need this shell script to begin with.

Comment: @BaummitAugen to be able to compile and run a file with a simple `./compile.sh` without worrying about its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't really help you with the actual error, BUT...

Why do you use set -e? You shouldn't skip errors, you should fix them...

Your CMakeLists.txt is also incorrectly structured. You should at the very first lines have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( filename )
```

Otherwise it's considered incorrect. It might work but it shouldn't. Before running CMake commands you have to specify what version is required to run the file.

Your SOURCES entries should have double quotes around them.

**UPDATE**

Turns out putting cmake_minimum_requirement(VERSION 2.8) first fixed it for the OP. After that point not much is required structurally in CMake, you can use your common sense for the rest, but having the version requirement first is a must.

Comment: mm I was using `set -e` to exit the shell script if any subsequent commands fails.

Is it possible to place `project( filename )` before `set(filename $ENV{env_filename})` ?

Comment: Oh right forgot set -e works in reverse of what I always think... lol. And no it isn't but I'm 99.9999% sure you can just use project($ENV{env_filename}) directly instead of going through the creation of an unnecessary variable.

Comment: And replacing `add_executable( ${filename} ${filename}.cpp ${SOURCES})` with `add_executable( $ENV{env_filename} $ENV{env_filename}.cpp ${SOURCES})` ?

Is it worth it to read the env. variable three times rather than creating a variable?

Comment: You can access the project name using the variable ${PROJECT_NAME}

Comment: mm that makes sense, ty.
BTW: reordering my CMakelists.txt seems to have solved the problem, so thanks again!

Comment: No problem :) I had some major issues getting into CMake as well but once you have that aha moment and once you get used to using the docs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/genindex.html you're gonna find it's an amazing tool for development.